# Assertion b2Assert(m_bodyCount > 0) showing an error

Tags: c++, box2d

I have the following code for deleting a Box2D body:

```
void b2World::DestroyBody(b2Body* b)
{
    b2Assert(m_bodyCount > 0);
    b2Assert(IsLocked() == false);
    if (IsLocked())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Delete the attached joints.
    b2JointEdge* je = b->m_jointList;
    while (je)
    {
        b2JointEdge* je0 = je;
        je = je->next;

        if (m_destructionListener)
        {
            m_destructionListener->SayGoodbye(je0->joint);
        }

        DestroyJoint(je0->joint);

        b->m_jointList = je;
    }
    b->m_jointList = NULL;

    // Delete the attached contacts.
    b2ContactEdge* ce = b->m_contactList;
    while (ce)
    {
        b2ContactEdge* ce0 = ce;
        ce = ce->next;
        m_contactManager.Destroy(ce0->contact);
    }
    b->m_contactList = NULL;

    // Delete the attached fixtures. This destroys broad-phase proxies.
    b2Fixture* f = b->m_fixtureList;
    while (f)
    {
        b2Fixture* f0 = f;
        f = f->m_next;

        if (m_destructionListener)
        {
            m_destructionListener->SayGoodbye(f0);
        }

        f0->DestroyProxies(&m_contactManager.m_broadPhase);
        f0->Destroy(&m_blockAllocator);
        f0->~b2Fixture();
        m_blockAllocator.Free(f0, sizeof(b2Fixture));

        b->m_fixtureList = f;
        b->m_fixtureCount -= 1;
    }
    b->m_fixtureList = NULL;
    b->m_fixtureCount = 0;

    // Remove world body list.
    if (b->m_prev)
    {
        b->m_prev->m_next = b->m_next;
    }

    if (b->m_next)
    {
        b->m_next->m_prev = b->m_prev;
    }

    if (b == m_bodyList)
    {
        m_bodyList = b->m_next;
    }

    --m_bodyCount;
    b->~b2Body();
    m_blockAllocator.Free(b, sizeof(b2Body));
}
```

When I close the game I get an exception, and the debugger points to the first line :

```
b2Assert(m_bodyCount>0);
```

What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An assertion failure happens when the expression returns 0, in this case when m_bodyCount is lower or equal to 0. This means that, whenever your code executes `b2World::DestroyBody();`, all the previously created `b2Body`s are already destroyed, if there ever were any created in the first place.

If you did create at least one (1) b2Body* instance, make sure that that specific instance isn't deleted multiple times in the code (in multiple instances of your `class A` for example), since very weird bugs can occur because of that.

Comment: my project has the next class:  class A with b2Body * and b2Fixture* pointers. Its destructor was deleting b2Body* pointer and i would get that assertion failure. But as i added deleting b2Fixture pointer in the very same destructor i seem to have issue get fixed. But that doesnt make sense to me as i thought all fixtures gets deleted with body all along.

Comment: You're correct regarding that fixtures contained in a b2Body* instance get destroyed during the b2Body* deletion. Like you wrote - it doesn't really make sense that the code isn't crashing when you're deleting the fixture the same time as the body but that it crashes when only the body is destroyed. Clearly a bug somewhere. Make sure that the b2Body* isn't used/deleted multiple times in the code, since very weird things can happen because of that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i was deleting every pointer to b2 objects in a class itself.